# Redundant processing in django form clean method and in view

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a Django form that accepts and processes an XML file (specifically, the view will need to parse a list of bands from an XML file exported from iTunes).  I plan on verifying that the XML parser runs without exceptions within the form clean() method.  However, I'd then like to have access to the parsed output list of bands in my view, without having to rerun the XML parser. (The XML parser can take non-negligible time for large files, so I do not want to run it multiple times.)

Is there any way I can make this happen without needing to run the parser twice? That is, can I access an arbitrary variable in the form clean() namespace from a view?

(I would really like to raise the ValidationError in the view, but I understand that is not possible.)

Thanks!

Comment: Just overload the form's `clean()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The clean() method of a Django form can be used like any general Python class.  Therefore, if computationally significant processing is performed in the clean() method, and the result of that processing is required in a view, one can append the resulting data as a member variable to the form class.